# How to go about making this type of combination?

Tags: java, string, combinations, nested-loops, conditional-statements

I have a four letter string of letters, such as ASDF and I want to find all 3 (three) letter combinations using these letters and the three letter combination does not need to form a real word.Ex.

AAA AAS AAD AAF
ADA ADS ADD ADF
...............
SSA SSD SSF SSS

I am relatively new to Java, having just learned how to use the String class and using loops and conditional statements. The only way that I know how to do this is by a massive and very tedious set of for loops and if statements that account for every possibility that could arise. This would look like:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      String combo = "";
      for(int counter = 1; counter <= 16; counter++){
           combo = "A";
           if(counter == 1){
              combo = combo + "AA";
           }
         // This would continue on for all the possibilities starting with "A" and
         // then move on to "S" as the lead character
       }
    }
```

I know that this is one of the worst ways to go about this problem, but I am really stuck as to how to do it another way. It would be easier if I had 3 letters and made the 3 letter combos, as then I could just get each letter from the array and just rearrange them, but as I'm only using 3 of the 4 letters it is more difficult. **Any advice on how to get this done in an more efficient manner?**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Good first question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_procedures).

Like this (not tested, don't have a Java compiler on my laptop).
Performance could probably be boosted by using StringBuilder.

```
static void printAllPossibilities(String charSet, int length) {
  printAllPossibilities_(charSet, length, "");
}

static void printAllPossibilities_(String charSet, int length, String temp) {
  if (length == 0) {
    System.out.println(temp);
    return;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < charSet.length(); i++)
    printAllPossibilities_(charSet, length - 1, temp + charSet.charAt(i));
}
```

Usage:

```
printAllPossibilities("ASDF", 4); // Print all 4-letter combinations out of "ASDF"
printAllPossibilities("bar", 2); // Print all 2-letter combinations out of "bar"
```

Comment: Oh, that wasn't me, I'm still trying to understand how to use the recursive function.

Comment: And I didn't blame you for downvoting ;)

I added an example how to use it.

Comment: When I downvoted it, it was a *blatant* placeholder answer with no detail or usefulness at all.

Comment: It was never a placeholder. It was asked for advice and I gave some. Just because there wasn't code in the first place doesn't mean it was no answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was able to get the answer and I am really amazed at how powerful the recursive function is! I would up vote you if I had enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

For the general case (all combinations of N chars out of M), the solution by @Qntm is exactly what you need... but, use a StringBuilder as he said, and just change the last character instead of constructing strings like 'temp + charSet.charAt(i)'.

If you need exactly 3 chars out of N, it's easier to just do 3 nested loops:

```
for (int char1 = 0; char1 < charSet.length(); char1++) {
    for (int char2 = 0; char2 < charSet.length(); char2++) {
        for (int char3 = 0; char3 < charSet.length(); char3++) {
            System.out.println(""+charSet.charAt(char1)+charSet.charAt(char2)+charSet.charAt(char3));
        }
    }
}
```